# AsyncTask in TabLayout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-tablayout

I've an app with TabLayout. Each tab is a Fragment and three of them contain an AsyncTask for doing heavy background operations. See below code example. The *backgroundLoadList* AsyncTask is calling *getTabNetworkList* to collect the data in an Array list.

Now, I'm starting the app and as I'm one tab before below tab, the system already preloads below tab in the background (*setOffscreenPageLimit* is set to 1). If I then rotate the screen, the *getTabNetworkList* is cancelled in the middle of it's Operation, is not attached to a context anymore, has no access to the resource strings in the catch clause and throws below exception. The AsyncTask is properly cancelled in *onDestroy*.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment Tab_Network{80b32b2 #2
>   id=0x7f090030 android:switcher:2131296304:2} not attached to a
>   context.

If I hardcode the resource strings in the catch clause, it works of course but the exception is still there.

Do you have an idea on how I could get rid of this exception? Many thanks!

**AsyncTask:**

```
private class backgroundLoadList extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, ArrayList<CustomDataStructure>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<CustomDataStructure> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        ArrayList<CustomDataStructure> result = getTabNetworkList();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<CustomDataStructure> customDataStructures) {
        adapter.listItems.retainAll(customDataStructures);
        adapter.listItems.addAll(customDataStructures);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        super.onPostExecute(customDataStructures);
    }
}
```

**Retrieving the list:**

```
private ArrayList<CustomDataStructure> getTabNetworkList() {
            CustomDataStructure item;
            ArrayList<CustomDataStructure> items = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
              item = new CustomDataStructure(getResources().getString(R.string.itemDescType), networkRoaming);
              items.add(item);
            // long list with further items is coded here...
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // Exception occurs on the next line because the context is not available anymore for getting the resources...
              item = new CustomDataStructure(getResources().getString(R.string.itemInfo), getResources().getString(R.string.textNotAvailable));
              items.add(item);
            }
            return items;
    }
```

Comment: Try to override `onAttach(Context context)` method inside your Fragment.

Comment: I already have an override of onAttach (Context context) --> (mContext = context;).

Comment: At which line you are getting issue? If you are getting issue with get strings from resources using `getResources().getString()` then try to retrieve using `getActivity().getResources().getString()`. But first where you are using this methods it's most important. If this whole code inside Fragment then you can use `getActivity().getResources().getString()`.

Comment: It occurs in getTabNetworkList, always at a different line. Probably, it depends how far the code has been processed when it's cancelled by the screen rotation. But the final issue is due to the missing link to the string ressource when the task is cancelled. I'll try with getActivity()...

Comment: Sure. try to use getResource() with getActivity() or context might fix your issue.

Comment: Now, it seems to work. However, for safety reasons, I have replaced the string resources in the catch statement by hardcoded strings.